# Baseboard installation floating floor without transitions

Tags: flooring, baseboard

When stalling floating floor without transitions- hallway, dining room, and living room- do you or can you install baseboards in the hallway before completing the other rooms, or is it all installed after ALL flooring is down?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to install the entire floor first and then do the baseboards.

I find that sometimes the floating floor may shift from continuing to install the remainder of the floor, *even when using the wedges around the perimeter*, and i may have to adjust it some. If the baseboard trim is already in place then there no way to get my adjusting bar in place to pound on it in order to move/adjust the floor.

Also because **i prefer to do one task to completion**.

Comment: Thank you for your input. That was my thoughts on doing it as well. That is how we are doing it. 